# flask route variable alters uriencoded string

Tags: python, flask

I am passing following url from my android app

```
http://server.com/core/put/18.00283670425415/59.353229999542236/%5BB%40463336a0/
```

the last parameter is a URI encoded string.
In Flask my route looks like

```
@server.route('/put/<long>/<lat>/<tagline>/')
def put(long, lat, tagline):
    return tagline
```

I get `[B@463336a0` as return and my url changes to

```
http://server.com/core/put/18.00283670425415/59.353229999542236/[B%40463336a0/
```

Whats happening here? this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is known as [percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). The `%5B` is the percent-encoding for `[`, and the `%40` is the percent-encoding for `@`.

You need to make sure that your Android app sends an *escaped* URI. In this particular case it would look something like this (simplified example for clarity):

```
>>> import urllib
>>> unescaped_url = '%5BB%40463336a0'
>>> escaped_url = urllib.quote(unescaped_url)
'%255BB%2540463336a0'
>>> unescaped_url == urllib.unquote(escaped_url)
True
```